# Jersey Jackson data entity filtering JsonMappingException on collection

Tags: json, jackson, jersey-2.0

I have an issue when trying to put in place the “selectable entity filtering”. I have an Abstract class like following one:

```
   // In your Pom
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
    </dependency>
....

    //Somewhere in resourceConfig: Register entity-filtering selectable feature.
    register(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class);
    property(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.QUERY_PARAM_NAME, "select");

    register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

…..

Before registering the “selectable entity filtering” all was working fine, I tested that a lot.

And after registering “selectable entity filtering” I have the following error:

```
[2016-02-15 17:25:36] - DEBUG EntityMapper:116 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Preparing query INSERT INTO 
[2016-02-15 17:25:43] - ERROR JsonMappingExceptionMapper:29 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Malformed Json!
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not resolve  PropertyFilter with id 'java.util.HashMap'; no FilterProvider configured
  at   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.findPropertyFilter(StdSerial izer.java:285)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:459)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29)
  at  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:851)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:650)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.writeTo(FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java:135)
  at    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
```

It seems that the issue comes from the

```
  StdSerializer.findPropertyFilter(StdSerializer.java:285)
  protected PropertyFilter findPropertyFilter(SerializerProvider provider,
        Object filterId, Object valueToFilter)
     throws JsonMappingException
  {
     FilterProvider filters = provider.getFilterProvider();
     // Not ok to miss the provider, if a filter is declared to be needed.
     if (filters == null) {
         throw new JsonMappingException("Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id '"+filterId+"'; no FilterProvider configured");
     }
     PropertyFilter filter = filters.findPropertyFilter(filterId, valueToFilter);
     // But whether unknown ids are ok just depends on filter provider; if we get null that's fine
    return filter;
  }
```

I don’t understand why the filtering is activated even in POST requests ? The strange thing is I didn’t put the “select” query parameter in the request!
Could you please help ?

Comment: The Jackson team says it's a Jersey issue. https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3574

Answer (score 5):

It seems that when you are using the **SelectableEntityFilteringFeature** and if you are putting Collection as an Entity in Response then you will get a **JsonMappingException**. For me it is a bug. The work around is you should encapsulate your collection into **GenericEntity** to be able to be serialized by Jersey-Jackson.

```
return Response.status(Status.OK)
       .entity(new GenericEntity<Set<MyEntity>>(entityIDs)     {}).build(); 
// Use GenericEntity to avoid JsonMappingException  because of the new flow with Filtering
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. But unfortunately it doesn't work if the collection is not the root object.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2933

I've tried personally and I do get back very weird behaviour. I know it's a Jersey-Jackson bug, @user3774109 any luck with the resolution?

Comment: As `jersey` moved to git, above `JERSEY-2933` is a [github](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3205) issue.

Comment: Wrapping in GenericEntity didn't work for me even if the collection is the root object

Answer (score 1):

I am using `SecurityEntityFilteringFeature`, and I ran upon the same error.

`StdSerializer.findPropertyFilter.getFilterProvider` and
`StdSerializer.findPropertyFilter` are returning `null`.

My solution is:

```
@Provider
public class JsonMappingExceptionOnCollectionResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestCtx, ContainerResponseContext responseCtx) throws IOException {
    ObjectWriterInjector.set(new ObjectWriterModifier() {

        @Override
        public ObjectWriter modify(EndpointConfigBase<?> endpoint, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> responseHeaders, Object valueToWrite, ObjectWriter w, JsonGenerator g) throws IOException {
            SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider();
            SimpleBeanPropertyFilter simpleBeanPropertyFilter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
                @Override
                protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            filterProvider.addFilter("your entity class", simpleBeanPropertyFilter);
            filterProvider.addFilter("your entity class", simpleBeanPropertyFilter);
            return w.with(filterProvider);
        }
    });
}
```

}